# Convert GIS Map Data To SVG?

Tags: django, image, svg, gis, arcgis

I'm Creating a web application with Django to show part of GIS Map to user.

I already know that it is possible to use Google map for this, but I want to create my own map !!

For this purpose, I need a SVG image from the map and then show it in my web page but the problem is, I don't know how can i convert part of GIS data to SVG.

Also it is important for me to have All the Layers Completely as they are in general GIS map data.

(My GIS Engine is ArcGIS)

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please help in this, I really need it !!!

Comment: ArcGIS has excellent support for python.  Have you checked the ERSI webite or the GIS group at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very old question and I just find it out in my profile. Although I changed the implementation of this project about 6 years ago, but currently I see that using ArcGIS you can export your data to SVG: [ExportToSVG](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttosvg.htm). This feature has been developed 2 or 3 years ago and I guess it was not available 6 years ago when I was searching for :)

Following documents / pages might be also useful for further readings:

1. [Using GIS data intelligence on the web with Scalable Vector
   Graphics (SVG)](http://www.svgopen.org/2005/papers/PublishingYourGISDataIntelligenceOnTheWebUsingSVG/index.html)
2. [Importing SVG into GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11476/importing-svg-into-gis)

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS has always allowed export to AI (Adobe Illustrator). An AI file can be easily converted to svg using [AI](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html), [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/), [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/ai-to-svg), etc.